# How can I recover 'iTunes Library (Damaged)'?

Tags: itunes, data-recovery

My iTunes library has disappeared and looking in the Music/iTunes folder, I see an 'iTunes Library (Damaged)' file. All of the music appears to still be there, so I am guessing it is just the database that is damaged. Is there a way to recover the library, like from the xml file? There is also a folder with Previous iTunes Libraries that are a couple months old. Can I just copy and rename one of those files?

Comment: what specific information do you want to recover ? playcounts and ratings ?

Comment: Yes... playlists, ratings, playcounts.

Comment: ok, once the recovery is done I suggest you to opt for a more robust way to store ratings, see http://tunecrux.com/resilient-id3-embedded-ratings (blog post of mine). For playcounts, Lastfm has the advantage to work with many music players.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple's documentation** on recreating your iTunes library if it is corrupt:

[iTunes: How to re-create your iTunes library and playlists](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1451)

Last Modified: April 07, 2011

Comment: This mentions that the xml file doesn't contain all the data in the database. What information is missing? Would it be better to use one of the Previous iTunes Libraries even though it is a bit out of date?

Comment: I don't have specifics but I believe you might lose your custom playlists, for instance, and might need to manually recreate them. All the ID3 tags are stored in the individual sound files themselves, so those should be preserved. And I would also guess that after a rebuild you would need to log into the iTunes Store and run the menu command to look for album artwork and download some of the artwork all over again.

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now dead.

Comment: Here's the archive of this link, for posterity: http://web.archive.org/web/20141024180525/http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1451

Answer (score 0):

I just copied one of the backup files from the 'Previous iTunes Libraries' folders and renamed it to iTunes Library which was quick and easy. I imagine the effectiveness of this solution depends on how old these files are as they are meant to be a backup for upgrading iTunes rather than a timely backup. It worked well for me though and I didn't have to re-create playlists or download album artwork.